# On Bitbucket pipelines how can I automate the rollback of a deployment if integration tests fail

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have setup my pipeline to include unit tests and integration tests.

Before deployment of my code, I run unit tests on the code in the pipeline, where if they fail the code will not be deployed.  My pipeline looks a little like this:

```
.build_&_test_template: &build_test_template |
  nvm install 18
  nvm use 18
  npm ci
  npm run coverage

pipelines:
  branches:
    uat:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to UAT
          deployment: test
          script:
            - *build_test_template
            - *shared_deploy_template
```

So if that `npm run coverage` fails the conditions I have set on my jasmine test configuration, the code will not get to the `shared_deploy_template`.

I have since added an integration step that would run after the code has deployed (`shared_deploy_template`), looking a little like this:

```
.shared_postman_test_template: &shared_postman_test_template |
  npm run postmanTests

pipelines:
  branches:
    uat:
      - step:
        ...
        script:
          - *build_test_template
          - *shared_deploy_template
          - *shared_postman_test_template
```

Now if there are any failures resulting from `shared_postman_test_template`, I'd like to be able to roll back the deployment automatically.

Is there a way to automate the rollback of a deployment based on testing conditions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a straightforward way to achieve that, but it might be possible.

First and foremost **the build, deploy and test scripts should run in separate steps**. Otherwise a failed test would signal bitbucket-pipelines that the deployment hadn't been done, so there would be "nothing to rollback". Also, if the build and the deploy instructions happened in the same step, re-deploying a past working version would force a rebuild, which is generally slower, unnecessary and potentially non-reproductible (YMMV).

Then, in the testing step you can use an [`after-script`](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/step-options/#After-script) section to handle the `$BITBUCKET_EXIT_CODE` variable that tells whether the `script` section failed. There, you could conditionally use Bitbucket API to re-trigger the previously successful deployment to that very environment.

Something like

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    uat:
      - step:
          name: Build
          script:
            - *build_test_template
          artifacts:
            - dist/whatever
      - step:
          name: Deploy
          deployment: test
          script:
            - *shared_deploy_template
      - step:
          name: Integration Tests
          script:
            - *shared_postman_test_template
          after-script:
            - if [ x$BITBUCKET_EXIT_CODE != x0 ]; then ???; fi
```

I think this is non-trivial and I can only point you to the [pipelines API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pipelines/#api-group-pipelines) and wish you the best of lucks.

---

If you can afford it, I think it is easier not to implement this in the CI system and instead use a deployment platform that handles health-checks and blue-green deployments out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  you say: "Also, re-deploying a past working version would force a rebuild", is the better way of doing this via a deployment platform then or is there any other alternative you'd recommend?

Comment: I rephrased that a little because I think it was unclear. I can't recommend a particular solution, as the suitability depends on your options and your experience, and I am no expert in the node landscape. Yet, the solution I depicted with bitbucket-pipelines feels not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

So from the help @N1ngu provided I have managed to get something clobbered together.

My pipelines file now looks like:

```yaml
pipelines:
  branches:
    uat:
      - step:
          name: Build
          script:
            - *export_uat_template
            - *build_test_template
          artifacts:
            - node_modules/**
      - step:
          name: Deploy
          deployment: test
          script:
            - *export_uat_template
            - *dev_deploy_template
            - *shared_deploy_template
          artifacts:
            - postman-testing.json
      - step:
          name: Integration Tests
          script:
            - *export_uat_template
            - *shared_postman_test_template
          after-script:
            - if [ x$BITBUCKET_EXIT_CODE != x0 ]; then npm run rollback; fi
```

The `after-script` now calls a **script** in my package.json called `rollback` which relates to the below JavaScript file.

And I have created a JavaScript file that makes use of the Bitbucket API:

```js
"use strict";

const https = require("https");

module.exports.rollback = async () => {
  const environments = await getEnvironments().catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  });

  const testEnvironment = environments.values
    .filter((env) => env.name === "Test")
    .at(-1);

  let allDeployments = [];

  for await (const deployments of fetchDeployments()) {
    allDeployments = allDeployments.concat(deployments.values);
  }

  const lastFiveSortedEnvironmentDeploysPipelines = allDeployments
    .filter(
      (deployment) => deployment.environment.uuid === testEnvironment.uuid
    )
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(b.last_update_time) - new Date(a.last_update_time);
    })
    .slice(0, 5)
    .map((deployment) => {
      return getPipeline(deployment.release.pipeline.uuid);
    });

  const pipelines = await Promise.all(
    lastFiveSortedEnvironmentDeploysPipelines
  ).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  });

  const successfullPipelinesSorted = pipelines
    .filter((pipeline) => pipeline?.state?.result?.name === "SUCCESSFUL")
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(b.created_on) - new Date(a.created_on);
    });

  if (successfullPipelinesSorted.length === 0)
    throw new Error("Manual rollback is required");

  console.log("starting a rollback");

  const body = {
    target: {
      commit: {
        hash: successfullPipelinesSorted[0].target.commit.hash,
        type: "commit",
      },
      selector: {
        type: "branches",
        pattern: "uat",
      },
      type: "pipeline_commit_target",
    },
  };

  const pipelineRun = await runPipeline(body).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  });

  console.log(JSON.stringify(pipelineRun));
};

const getEnvironments = async () => {
  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
  };
  const getEnvironmentsPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    https
      .get(
        `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${process.env.BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE}/${process.env.BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/environments`,
        { headers },
        (response) => {
          let s = "";
          response.on("data", (d) => {
            s += d;
          });

          response.on("end", () => {
            const body = JSON.parse(s);
            res(body);
          });
        }
      )
      .on("error", (err) => {
        rej(err);
      });
  });
  return await getEnvironmentsPromise;
};

const getDeployments = async (
  url = `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${process.env.BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE}/${process.env.BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/deployments?pagelen=100`
) => {
  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
  };

  const deploymentsPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    https
      .get(`${url}`, { headers }, (response) => {
        let s = "";
        response.on("data", (d) => {
          s += d;
        });

        response.on("end", () => {
          const body = JSON.parse(s);
          res(body);
        });
      })
      .on("error", (err) => {
        rej(err);
      });
  });
  return deploymentsPromise;
};

const getPipeline = async (pipelineId) => {
  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
  };

  const getPipelinePromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    https
      .get(
        `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${process.env.BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE}/${process.env.BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/pipelines/${pipelineId}`,
        { headers },
        (response) => {
          let s = "";
          response.on("data", (d) => {
            s += d;
          });

          response.on("end", () => {
            const body = JSON.parse(s);
            res(body);
          });
        }
      )
      .on("error", (err) => {
        rej(err);
      });
  });
  return await getPipelinePromise;
};

const runPipeline = async (body) => {
  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };

  const runPipelinePromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const req = https
      .request(
        {
          hostname: "api.bitbucket.org",
          path: `/2.0/repositories/${process.env.BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE}/${process.env.BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/pipelines`,
          method: "POST",
          headers,
        },
        (response) => {
          let s = "";

          response.on("error", (err) => {
            rej(err);
          });

          response.on("data", (d) => {
            s += d;
          });

          response.on("end", () => {
            const body = JSON.parse(s);
            res(body);
          });
        }
      )
      .on("error", (err) => {
        rej(err);
      });
    req.write(JSON.stringify(body));
    req.end();
  });

  return await runPipelinePromise;
};

async function* fetchDeployments() {
  let finished = false;
  let url;
  while (!finished) {
    const response = await getDeployments(url);
    yield response;
    finished = Boolean(response?.next) === false;
    url = response.next;
  }
}
```

This will go through your last deployments for a specific environment, order them by date then get the last 5 and see if there were any successful deployments within those 5.  It'll then trigger a new deployment of the last successful deployment.  If there were no successful deployments in the last 5 deployments, it'll error out suggesting a Manual deploy is required.

The script will need altering to match your own environment since it's hardcoded with certain values.